# How did the author get these transitional probabilities in this markov model?

Tags: markov-chains

I am referring to this: http://www.mdpi.com/1999-5903/9/3/37/htm

In Chapter 3.1, the author assumes a scenario where in the first 50ms of an observation, pages 1 and 2 are dirty. In the next 50ms, pages 2, 3 and 4 are dirty. And in the last 50ms, pages 1, 4 and 5 are dirty. He then proceeds to assert that the probability of transitioning from 1 to 2 = 50%, 1 to 3 = 25%, 1 to 4 = 25%, etc and then outlines the entire state diagram. Note, author calls them w1, w2, etc. I prefer to just refer to them as numbers 1, 2, etc.

My issue is that I do not understand how he got these probabilities. What I was expecting was that the author would outline a sequence: 1,2,2,3,4,1,4,5 and the P(1 to 2) would be = # of (1 to 2)s / # of 1s = 50%. 
P(1 to 3) = # of (1 to 3)s / # of 1s = 0% and so.

I do not claim that I remotely really understand Markov models/chains that well so please, keep answers simple and not TOO abstract and very easy to understand. From what ive seen online, markov models can be very abstract and confusing.

Comment: No idea what they are doing. It's really fuzzily written.

Comment: I think your way sounds reasonable. If I get what you mean then that's quite close to how I did it in my first source coder.